# c++ application is crashing when allocating a const char* const buffer

Tags: c++, libpq

I'm having trouble with creating a buffer in my c++ application. I am being forced to create a const char* const* buffer so that I can use libpq's PQexecParams function.

```
PGresult *PQexecParams(PGconn *conn,
                    const char *command,
                    int nParams,
                    const Oid *paramTypes,
                    const char * const *paramValues,
                    const int *paramLengths,
                    const int *paramFormats,
                    int resultFormat);
```

Here is some code to reproduce the issue I'm getting STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW exceptions when I allocate anything larger than 2.5MB for the buffer (for example running the program and specifying a size of 2621440.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        cout << "Buffer size Testing" << endl;
        cout << "==========================" << endl;
        int size;
        cout << "Size of buffer?" << endl;
        cout << "Size: ";
        cin >> size;
        try {
        const char * const *buffer[size];
        } catch (...){
                cout << "An error was encountered!" << endl;
                exit(1);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

What is the correct way to create a large buffer (2.5MB) for use with PQexecParams?

Comment: [`std::vector<char> buffer(size);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) The use `buffer.data()` as the pointer. And note that since yours is a buffer of `const char`, how do you ever expect to be able to store the values?

Comment: Don't add tags for unrelated languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seg Fault when initializing array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815232/seg-fault-when-initializing-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your code is doing is allocation a big array of pointers on stack, which is why you get stack overflow exception.

The proper way to allocate buffer on heap would be:

```
char* buffer = new char[size]; // add consts where you need them
```

However, I would follow suggestion from @BoBTFish and just use:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(size);
```

You can access the data buffer by either `buffer.data()` or by taking address of the first element: `&buffer[0]`. Vector will free allocated memory in its destructor.